# Rails / ActiveRecord - Single Table Inheritance - overriding type field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

Is it possible to override the name of this colummn?  I'm changing some parts of my applications to use STI and there are other fields in use for.  I would also prefer it to be of type integer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern Rails, you'd use [`inheritance_column=`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-inheritance_column-3D) (as [panckreous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467096/479863) noted):

```
class M < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = 'whatever'
  #...
end
```

In older versions of Rails (i.e. what was around when this answer was originally written), you'd use [`set_inheritance_column`] to change the name:

> Sets the name of the inheritance column to use to the given value, or (if the value is `nil` or `false`) to the value returned by the given block.

The column still has to be a string (or `text`) as AR will want to put [the class name in there](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance):

> **Single table inheritance**
>
> Active Record allows inheritance by storing the name of the class in a column that is named “type” by default.

Answer (score 7):

According to the code in ActiveRecord::ModelSchema (3.2), the `set_inheritance_column` method is now deprecated and you should use `self.inheritance_column = column`